# Yii2 Grid View Filtering using ajax not Pjax

Tags: ajax, gridview, yii2, filtering, pjax

How to get the value of the attribute in yii2 using ajax not Pjax to filter the Gridview ?

Comment: Please give more details what exacly you want. For not is it not clear

Comment: what you have tried so far, please show us

Answer (score 0):

easily you can do your own you want by sending  Ajax request to any controller you want and return data as Json to read it by javasscript .

here is a sample file (you can put in any .js file and bind in from your layout or jsRegister function )

test.js:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url : '/site/countor?id='+pathArray[2],
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(output) {


      alert(output);

    },

    contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json'

});}}
```

siteController counter action :

```
 public function actionCountor($id) { 
                $p1 = new View();
                $p1->ip = Yii::$app->request->getUserIP();
                $p1->post_id = $id;
                if ($p1->save()) {
                    $arr = array('id'=>$p1->id;
                    return json_encode($arr); 
                }
 }
```